How to Restrict Axis Scrolling Beyond Specific Values in LightningChartJS?
I am working with LightningChartJS in a React application and am trying to limit the y-axis scrolling range so that the chart does not allow scrolling above or below specified values. I have already checked a similar solution here: Limit scrollable range in LightningChartJS and attempted to apply but without success.
Despite following the example in the documentation, the y-axis does not restrict the user from scrolling to any value they desire. Here is the code snippet I am working with:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { lightningChart } from "@arction/lcjs";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const lc = lightningChart({
      license: "your-licence",
    });
    const chart = lc.ChartXY({ container: "chart1" });
    chart.setTitle("");
    const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY();

    // Attempt to set minimum zoom level
    axisY.setIntervalRestrictions({ intervalMin: -10 });
    // Attempt to set maximum zoom level
    axisY.setIntervalRestrictions({ intervalMax: 40 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id={"chart1"} style={{ width: "200px", height: "500px" }}></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


use example1 instead, example2&3 are restrict zoom in level not range

Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the formatting documentation for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.
